# A Standalone Spark app with errors of MojoExecutionException,InvocationTargetException and OutOfMemoryError

Tags: maven, out-of-memory, apache-spark

I run a Standalone Spark app with Maven but I got some errors. There are one master and three slaves in my cluster, and the Spark version is 0.9.1. The pom.xml as follows.

```
<groupId>spark</groupId>
<artifactId>testspark</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>testspark</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>Akka repository</id>
    <url>http://repo.akka.io/releases</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>3.8.1</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.1</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My Spark app is as follows.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String sparkHome = System.getenv("SPARK_HOME");
    System.out.println(sparkHome);
    String logFile = "/usr/Java/spark-0.9.1-bin-hadoop1/README.md";//spark:
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf();
    conf.setMaster("spark://192.168.23.123:7077")
       .setAppName("Simple App")
       .setSparkHome(System.getenv("SPARK_HOME"))
       .setJars(new String[] { "target/testspark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" })
       .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaRDD<String> logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache();
    long numAs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call(String s) {
            return s.contains("a");
        }
    }).count();

    long numBs = logData.filter(new Function<String, Boolean>() {
        public Boolean call(String s) {
            return s.contains("b");
        }
    }).count();


    System.out.println("Lines with a: " + numAs + ", lines with b: " + numBs);
    sc.stop();
}
```

My master is 192.168.23.123, and after running the errors appear as follows.

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: An exception occured while executing the Java class. null
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo.execute(ExecJavaMojo.java:345)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:293)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted: Task 0.0:1 failed 4 times (most recent failure: Exception failure: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1028)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1026)
at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1026)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$processEvent$10.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:619)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$processEvent$10.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:619)
at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.processEvent(DAGScheduler.scala:619)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$start$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(DAGScheduler.scala:207)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:498)
at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:456)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:237)
at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:219)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:386)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

As for the OutOfMemoryError, I set the sentence  .set("spark.executor.memory", "1g"), but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score -1):

Java applications are allowed to use only limited amount of memory. This limit is specified during the application startup. To make things more complex, the Java memory is separated to two different regions. These regions are called heap space and permgen.

The “java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space” error you are facing is be triggered when you try to add more data into the heap space area in memory, but the size of this data is larger than the JVM can accommodate in the Java heap space.

In order to solve this, usually increasing heap size by adding (or increasing if present) the value of -Xmx property in your JVM startup parameters.